# remove 1st and last observations within a group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where I'd like to remove the 1st and last observations within every group.  I've tested out the following and it does what I'm hoping to:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
v2 = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5))

df %>%
group_by(v1) %>%
slice(-c(1,n())

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   v1 [3]
     v1    v2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     1     4
4     2     2
5     2     3
6     2     4
7     3     2
8     3     3
9     3     4
```

But when I run it with my actual df, it removes all of my observations.  How can I fix this?

Below is the code for my actual data, as well as a subset of my dataframe.

```
df.detTot2 <- df.detTot %>% 
  ungroup() %>% #added in incase there was additional grouping from previous
  group_by(ID, recvDeployName2, doy.local, ts.h.local) %>%
  slice(-c(1, n()))

dim(df.detTot2)
[1] 0 8

dput(df.detTot[1:100,])
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NB2014.12", 
"NB2014.13", "NB2014.14", "NB2014.15", "NB2014.16", "NB2014.42", 
"NB2014.43", "NB2014.44", "NB2014.45", "NB2014.47", "NB2014.48", 
"NB2014.49", "NB2014.70", "NB2014.71", "NB2014.72", "NB2014.73", 
"NB2014.74", "NB2014.75", "NB2014.76", "NB2014.77", "NB2014.78", 
"NB2014.79", "NB2014.80", "NB2014.81", "NB2015.156", "NB2015.157", 
"NB2015.158", "NB2015.159", "NB2015.160", "NB2015.312", "NB2015.313", 
"NB2015.314", "NB2015.315", "NB2015.316", "NB2015.317", "NB2015.318", 
"NB2015.320", "NB2015.321", "NB2015.322", "NB2015.323", "NB2015.324", 
"NB2015.325", "NB2015.326", "NB2015.327", "NB2015.328", "NB2015.329", 
"NB2015.330", "NB2015.331", "NB2015.332", "NB2015.333", "NB2015.334", 
"NB2015.335", "NB2015.336", "NB2015.337", "NB2015.338", "NB2015.339", 
"NB2015.340", "NB2015.341", "NB2015.342", "NB2015.343", "NB2015.344", 
"NB2015.345", "NB2015.346", "NB2015.347", "NB2015.348", "NB2015.349", 
"NB2015.350", "NB2015.351", "NB2018.10", "NB2018.11", "NB2018.12", 
"NB2018.13", "NB2018.14", "NB2018.15", "NB2018.16", "NB2018.17", 
"NB2018.18", "NB2018.19", "NB2018.20", "NB2018.21", "NB2018.22", 
"NB2018.23", "NB2018.24", "NB2018.25", "NB2018.26", "NB2018.27", 
"NB2018.28", "NB2018.29", "NB2018.30", "NB2018.31", "NB2018.32", 
"NB2018.33", "NB2018.34", "NB2018.35", "NB2018.37", "NB2018.38", 
"NB2018.39", "NB2018.40", "NB2018.41", "NB2018.42", "NB2018.43", 
"NB2018.44", "NB2018.45", "NB2018.46", "NB2018.47", "NB2018.48", 
"NB2018.49", "NB2018.5", "NB2018.50", "NB2018.51", "NB2018.52", 
"NB2018.53", "NB2018.54", "NB2018.55", "NB2018.56", "NB2018.57", 
"NB2018.58", "NB2018.59", "NB2018.6", "NB2018.60", "NB2018.61", 
"NB2018.62", "NB2018.63", "NB2018.64", "NB2018.7", "NB2018.8", 
"NB2018.9"), class = "factor"), speciesEN = c("Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
"Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow"), recvDeployName2 = c("Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
"Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar"), year = c(2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014
), ts.h.local = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), doy.local = c(183, 183, 
183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 
183, 183, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 
184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 
185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 186, 186, 186, 
186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 
187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 
187, 187, 187, 187, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 
188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188), nDet = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 
23, 7, 41, 0, 0, 28, 3, 35, 39, 29, 40, 0, 0, 0, 13, 35, 43, 
106, 136, 116, 77, 43, 149, 130, 60, 44, 169, 26, 2, 6, 48, 38, 
38, 127, 50, 28, 74, 162, 211, 138, 85, 63, 63, 67, 30, 2, 0, 
0, 71, 2, 53, 161, 143, 63, 107, 26, 0, 0, 260, 168, 54, 46, 
132, 291, 171, 204, 154, 75, 198, 80, 155, 205, 158, 203, 137, 
59, 47, 170, 36, 95, 131, 167, 124, 100, 130, 131, 247, 247, 
102, 177, 191, 93, 171, 180, 127), dayNight = c("day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), vars = c("ID", "speciesEN", "recvDeployName2", "year", "doy.local", 
"ts.h.local"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
    18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
    30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
    42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
    54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 
    66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 
    78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 
    90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L), group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("NB2014.12", "NB2014.13", "NB2014.14", "NB2014.15", 
    "NB2014.16", "NB2014.42", "NB2014.43", "NB2014.44", "NB2014.45", 
    "NB2014.47", "NB2014.48", "NB2014.49", "NB2014.70", "NB2014.71", 
    "NB2014.72", "NB2014.73", "NB2014.74", "NB2014.75", "NB2014.76", 
    "NB2014.77", "NB2014.78", "NB2014.79", "NB2014.80", "NB2014.81", 
    "NB2015.156", "NB2015.157", "NB2015.158", "NB2015.159", "NB2015.160", 
    "NB2015.312", "NB2015.313", "NB2015.314", "NB2015.315", "NB2015.316", 
    "NB2015.317", "NB2015.318", "NB2015.320", "NB2015.321", "NB2015.322", 
    "NB2015.323", "NB2015.324", "NB2015.325", "NB2015.326", "NB2015.327", 
    "NB2015.328", "NB2015.329", "NB2015.330", "NB2015.331", "NB2015.332", 
    "NB2015.333", "NB2015.334", "NB2015.335", "NB2015.336", "NB2015.337", 
    "NB2015.338", "NB2015.339", "NB2015.340", "NB2015.341", "NB2015.342", 
    "NB2015.343", "NB2015.344", "NB2015.345", "NB2015.346", "NB2015.347", 
    "NB2015.348", "NB2015.349", "NB2015.350", "NB2015.351", "NB2018.10", 
    "NB2018.11", "NB2018.12", "NB2018.13", "NB2018.14", "NB2018.15", 
    "NB2018.16", "NB2018.17", "NB2018.18", "NB2018.19", "NB2018.20", 
    "NB2018.21", "NB2018.22", "NB2018.23", "NB2018.24", "NB2018.25", 
    "NB2018.26", "NB2018.27", "NB2018.28", "NB2018.29", "NB2018.30", 
    "NB2018.31", "NB2018.32", "NB2018.33", "NB2018.34", "NB2018.35", 
    "NB2018.37", "NB2018.38", "NB2018.39", "NB2018.40", "NB2018.41", 
    "NB2018.42", "NB2018.43", "NB2018.44", "NB2018.45", "NB2018.46", 
    "NB2018.47", "NB2018.48", "NB2018.49", "NB2018.5", "NB2018.50", 
    "NB2018.51", "NB2018.52", "NB2018.53", "NB2018.54", "NB2018.55", 
    "NB2018.56", "NB2018.57", "NB2018.58", "NB2018.59", "NB2018.6", 
    "NB2018.60", "NB2018.61", "NB2018.62", "NB2018.63", "NB2018.64", 
    "NB2018.7", "NB2018.8", "NB2018.9"), class = "factor"), speciesEN = c("Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", 
    "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow", "Bank Swallow"), recvDeployName2 = c("Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", 
    "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar", "Tantramar"), year = c(2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014), doy.local = c(183, 
    183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 183, 
    183, 183, 183, 183, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 
    184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 185, 185, 185, 
    185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 185, 
    185, 185, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 
    186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 186, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 
    187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 188, 
    188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 
    188, 188, 188), ts.h.local = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 20L, 21L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 20L, 21L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("ID", 
"speciesEN", "recvDeployName2", "year", "doy.local", "ts.h.local"
), drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: In your first block, you've got `(n)` where you probably want `n()`

Comment: Your data has 100 rows, and once you group it by this combination of columns, you have 100 groups. i.e. there's only one row per group. So removing the *first* row is means removing the *only* row for each group. Replace your `slice` with `count` to see what I mean

Comment: Thanks @camille.  I've corrected the typo above, and modified the grouping as was suggested below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not `group_by` `ts.h.local`

```
df %>% 
     ungroup() %>% 
     group_by(ID, recvDeployName2, doy.local) %>%
     slice(-c(1, n()))
```

Comment: @tnt yw:-) happy coding